# Auto complete function not working properly jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I have a textbox that needs to be autocompleted when user types in atleast 2 characters, however, it's simply not working. I have almost the exact same code in another form and it is working fine. Any input will be greatly appreciated! I did not post the C# because, as you see, I console.log the list to ensure the ajax post was successful (it is). Also, the jquery and jquery-ui scripts are declared in the master page of this app.

```js
var shipTo = $('#txtShipTo')
var shipFrom = $('#txtShipFrom')
var addressList = []

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Shipping.aspx/fillList',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (r) {
            $.each(r.d, function (index, value) {
                addressList.push(value)
            })
            console.log(addressList)
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Fail")
        }
    })
})

shipFrom.autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: addressList,
})
```

```html
<%@ Page Title="Shipping Request" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Base.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Shipping.aspx.cs" Inherits="Shipping" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div class="container" id="fromContainer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 col" id="shipFromDiv">
                <label for = "txtShipFrom">Shipped From</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipFrom" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Begin typing..." aria-label=""></asp:TextBox>
                <label for = "txtAddress1">Address 1</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress1" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                <label for = "txtAddress2">Address 2</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress2" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-5">
                        <label for = "txtCity">City</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-3">
                        <label for = "txtState">State</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-4">
                        <label for = "txtZip">Zip</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col">
                        <label for = "txtCountry">Country</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col">
                        <label for = "txtCode">Code</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col" id="shipToDiv">
                <label for = "txtShipTo">Shipped To</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtShipTo" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Begin typing..."></asp:TextBox>
                <label for = "txtAddress3">Address 1</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress3" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                <label for = "txtAddress4">Address 2</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress4" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col">
                        <label for = "txtCity">City</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col">
                        <label for = "txtState">State</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col">
                        <label for = "txtZip">Zip</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col">
                        <label for = "txtCountry">Country</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col">
                        <label for = "txtCode">Code</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" class="form-control" disabled></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="JavaScript2.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Could you remove the "," after : source: addressList, an try it again ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.

Comment: Any errors on the browser console ? What is happening ? Have you tried adding the .focus(function() {
         $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
     }); and see what happens when it receives focus ?

Comment: Agree checking if any errors in console. Also could you console.log(r) inside the success ajax callback?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. It appears that its not recognizing $('#txtShipFrom') for some reason. I have the all jquery source code in the master page and even tried moving it to this form also, and still no luck..

Comment: try placing $('#txtShipTo'), $('#txtShipFrom') etc INSIDE the document ready

Comment: I converted the asp.net textbox into an html input and now it works. Can anyone explain why this is?